# Как наиболее правильно удалить элемент из середины deque?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Всем привет!
Требуется удалить элемент из deque. Я использую еще один deque, чтобы запушить туда все элеметы кроме удаляемого, тем самым добиваюсь нужного результата, код ниже:

```
int main(){

        deque<int> list1;

        for (int i=0; i<10; i++){

            list1.push_back(i);

        }

        deque<int> list2;

        int deleteElement = 5;

        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){

            if (list1[i] != deleteElement){
                list2.push_back(list1[i]);
            }

        }

}
```

Но так получается достаточно долго, так как я копирую в другой deque все элементы кроме удаляемого. И у меня вопрос, существует ли более изящный способ удаления элемента из середины deque?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать стандартный алгоритм `remove` и метод `erase`:

```
list1.erase(remove(list1.begin(), list1.end(), 5), list1.end());
```

Comment: Возникает такая ошибка
[Error] cannot convert 'std::deque<int>::iterator {aka std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int remove(const char*)'

Comment: @Kotysh [Не возникает](https://wandbox.org/permlink/hzAsZbpv5hGhMry0).

Comment: пробую в онлайн компиляторах, все тоже самое, ошибка.

Comment: @Kotysh Я же указал ссылку на онлайн компилятор, там этой ошибки не возникает.

Comment: Да, вижу, я не указал <algorithm>